# Можно ли подать на вход функции строку?

Tags: jquery, объекты

Помогите пожалуйста. Хочу оптимизировать код слайдера. На вход функции s.displayRight подается oBlock из s.showInfoRight. Я хочу подать два объекта, чтобы направление 'left' определялось из функции s.showInfoRight  (объект - direct). Но расстояние не высчитывается и слайдер зависает. Можно ли так вообще делать?

```
function Services(sSelector){
var s = this;


s.main = function(){
    s.init(sSelector);
    s.link                  = s.find('.breadNav_link');
    s.left                  = s.find('.arrow__left');
    s.right                 = s.find('.arrow__right');
    s.block                 = s.find('.services__block');
    s.current           = 0;
    s.max                   = s.block.length;
    s.x = 2000;


    s.right.bind('click', s.showNext);
    s.left.bind('click', s.showPrev);
    s.link.bind('click', s.showInfo);
}

s.showNext = function(){
    s.showInfoRight(+1);
}

s.showPrev = function(){
    s.showInfoLeft(-1);
}

s.curObject = function(oCurrent){
    var curObject = s.find('.services__block:eq(' + oCurrent + ')');

    curObject.animate({opacity: 0}, 300, function(){
            curObject.removeClass('services__block_active');
        });
}

s.length = function(oLength){
    if(oLength >= s.max){
        s.current = 0;}
    else if(oLength <0){
        s.current = s.max -1;}
}
s.showInfoRight = function(iShift){
    s.curObject(s.current);
    s.current+=iShift;
    s.length(s.current); 
    s.displayRight((s.find('.services__block:eq(' + s.current + ')')), 'left');
}

s.displayRight = function(oBlock, direct){
    setTimeout(function(){
        oBlock.stop().animate('{'+ direct + ': 2000}', 50, function(){
            oBlock.addClass('services__block_active').css('opacity', 1);
        });
        oBlock.animate({left: 0}, 900);
    }, 300);
}

s.showInfoLeft = function(iShift){
    s.curObject(s.current);
    s.current+=iShift;
    s.length(s.current); 

    s.displayLeft(s.find('.services__block:eq(' + s.current + ')')
    );
}

s.displayLeft= function(oBlock){
    setTimeout(function(){
        oBlock.animate({right: 2000, left: -2000}, 50, function(){
            oBlock.addClass('services__block_active').css('opacity', 1);
        });
    oBlock.animate({right: 0, left:0}, 900);
    }, 300);
};

$(document).ready(s.main);
}
Services.prototype = new Component();
```

Comment: предполагаю ты хочешь [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015): `animate({[direct]: 2000}`

Comment: Спасибо! То, что было нужно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дальнейшее я пишу из предположения что в direct находится строка по типу "left" и "right";

1. Согласно документации [функция animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) ожидает первым параметром Plain Object. Синтаксически передать ей строку конечно можно, но она при этом понятное дело не обработает.
2. Неявных приведений типов в js конечно хватает, но конверт строки в объект и обратно это слишком хитрая операция. По умолчанию ее делать было бы весьма опрометчиво даже для такого вольного языка как js. Никто ничего куда не конвертит, функция строку не обрабатывает, все валится, дети плачут, над миром нависает тьма.
3. Приходит в голову. А раз такое дело, почему бы не сконвертить строку ручками? Ну в теории такое возможно с помощью `JSON.parse`, но делать так в большинстве случаев не надо, есть более нормальные методы.
4. Самое распространенное решение - заранее подготовить объект и передать подготовленный объект на вход функции.
   Если мы заранее не знаем имя ключа объекта, то есть оно хранится в переменной, то через точку его задать нельзя. Но можно через квадратные скобки.

   ```
   var animateParams = {};  
   animateParams[direct] = 2000;
   ```

   И потом вызвать в духе:

   ```
   oBlock.stop().animate(anmiateParams,//какие-то еще параметры
   ```
5. В общем много лет все делали как в пункте 4. Но в прошлом году окончательно приняли обновленный стандарт javascript, который нормально поддерживается *современными* браузерами и позволяет писать короче и красивей, как вам сказал Grundy в комментариях:

   ```
   animate({[direct]: 2000}, //какие-то еще параметры
   ```

   Называется это [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). [Поддержка браузерами очень хорошая.](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает